# After sending files through socket, how can i send other data by Java

Tags: java, file, sockets

I'm sending files through java socket by codes below:
client:

```java
File file = new File(filePath);
if (file.exists()) {
    this.rafin = new RandomAccessFile(filePath, "r");
    this.dos = new DataOutputStream(super.getOutputStream());
    rafin.seek(start); // 找到位置
    // 写入文件名
    dos.writeUTF(file.getName()+"."+order);
    // 写入文件切片个数
    dos.writeInt(fileSplitNum);
    // 写入sendIp
    dos.writeUTF(localIp);
    // 写入文件落盘时间
    dos.writeUTF(lastModifiedDate);
    dos.flush();
    log.info("文件名为："+file.getName()+"."+order);
    long fileLength = end - start + 1;
    byte[] bytes = new byte[1024 * 8];
    
    // 计算循环
    long times = fileLength / bytes.length;
    
    int length;
    long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
    // ======================核心传输逻辑==========================
    MessageDigest md5 = MessageDigest.getInstance("MD5");
    for (int i = 0;i < times; i++) {
        length = rafin.read(bytes, 0, bytes.length);
        md5.update(bytes, 0, length); // md5计算
        dos.write(bytes, 0, length);
    }
    long last = fileLength % bytes.length;
    if (last != 0) {
        length = rafin.read(bytes, 0, (int) last);
        md5.update(bytes, 0, (int) last); // md5
        dos.write(bytes, 0, length);
    }
    // ========================核心传输逻辑结束==============================
    String fileMd5 = DigestUtil.toHexString(md5.digest());
    // 将文件的md5编码传入server
     dos.writeUTF(fileMd5); // ******* I want to send md5 to server at here
     dos.flush();
    log.info("第{}切片的md5加密密钥为：{}", order, fileMd5);
    long end = System.currentTimeMillis();
    
    String file_trans_stat = dis.readUTF();
    log.info("文件传输状态：{}", file_trans_stat);
    latch.countDown(); // latch锁减一
    log.info(String.format("%s 传输完毕，用时：%.2f秒%n",Thread.currentThread().getName(),(double)(end-start)/1000));
}
```

server:

```java
dis = new DataInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
// 文件名
String fileName = dis.readUTF();
// 文件切片个数
int fileSplitNum = dis.readInt();
// sendIp
String sendIp = dis.readUTF();
// 文件落盘时间
String lastModifiedDate = dis.readUTF();
// 计时表
ThreadLocal<StopWatch> threadLocal = new ThreadLocal<>();
threadLocal.set(new StopWatch());
threadLocal.get().start();
String fileNameTmp = fileName+".tmp";
log.info("接收文件夹为：{}", fileDir);
File directory = new File(fileDir);
if (!directory.exists()) {
    directory.mkdir();
}
File file = new File(directory.getAbsolutePath() + File.separatorChar + fileNameTmp);
FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(file);

byte[] bytes = new byte[1024 * 8];
int length;
MessageDigest md5 = MessageDigest.getInstance("MD5");
while ( (length = dis.read(bytes, 0, bytes.length)) != -1 ) {
    fos.write(bytes, 0, length);
    md5.update(bytes, 0, length);
    fos.flush();
}
fos.close();
String clientFileMd5 = dis.readUTF();   //*********** I want to receive md5 at here, but it seems doesn't work
log.info("client传来的{}的加密密钥为:{}", fileNameTmp, clientFileMd5);
String fileMd5 = DigestUtil.toHexString(md5.digest());
log.info("切片{}的md5加密密钥为: {}", fileNameTmp, fileMd5);
```

I want to send the file's md5 to server after sending the file to verify whether the file is ok, but the code seems doesn't work, how can i adjust the code

the code of sending md5 I have tried is in the exegesis which is purple color

what I have tried is in the code

Comment: Hello and welcome. Please post your code as text directly in the question, not as pictures.

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: thanks and i will delete this one and post a new one

Comment: please edit the question instead of deleting and posting a new one

Comment: The server needs to know where the file stops and the MD5 starts. One way to do this is to send the length first, and then when the server has read that many bytes, it knows the file has finished and the MD5 is next.